# MySQL Triggers use different TIMEZONE

Tags: mysql, triggers, timezone, mariadb

I have created a trigger to set a uniq name (ref) for the purchase, using timezone for create_date field.
It worked fine until I noticed duplicate references, one of the refs have the date in the reference not matching the date in the create_date field (1 day of diff) ?!!

```
BEGIN
SET NEW.reference := concat(
(SELECT name FROM provider WHERE id = NEW.provider_id),
 date_format(NEW.create_date, '%Y%m%d'), '/',
  (SELECT LPAD(IFNULL(MAX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(reference, '/', -1)) + 1, 0), 3, '0') 
   FROM purchase
   WHERE date_format(NEW.create_date, '%Y%m%d') = date_format(create_date, '%Y%m%d')
      AND NEW.provider_id = provider_id
  )
);
END
```

Any one have an idea of what happing or a better approch?

PS: The date in the create_date field is the correct one, the date in the NEW.create_date that is used in the ref is wrong (maybe b/c of the client timezone as we send it as string)

---

Update

Tables structure:

Purchase:

```
CREATE TABLE purchase
(
  id             int          auto_increment primary key,
  provider_id    int          not null,
  create_date    timestamp    null,
  create_user    int          null,
  change_date    timestamp    null,
  change_user    int          null,
  group_id       int          null,
  reference      varchar(45)  null
);

CREATE INDEX purchase_reference_index ON purchase (reference);
CREATE INDEX purchase_provider_index ON purchase (provider_id);
```

Provider:

```
CREATE TABLE provider
(
  id           int auto_increment primary key,
  name         varchar(45) null,
  constraint name_uniq unique (name)
);
```

Example of the query:

```
INSERT INTO purchase (provider_id, create_date, create_user, group_id)
VALUE (4, '2019-01-30 02:36:58', 1, 3);
```

`2019-01-30 02:36:58` is saved in the database as `2019-01-29 23:36:58` when I select it from a session the use server timezone.

Function that I am using to setup the timezone:

```
function update_timezone($timezone = null)
{
    if (is_null($timezone)) $timezone = __SERVER_TIMEZONE;

    if (in_array($timezone, timezone_identifiers_list())) {
        date_default_timezone_set($timezone);

        $tz = (new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get())))->format('P');
        $conn = Database::Connect();
        Database::NonQuery("SET time_zone = '$tz';", $conn);
    }
}
```

What I am expecting:

```
reference === 'provider_name20190129/00X'
```

What I am getting:

```
reference === 'provider_name20190130/00Y'
```

How to reproduce the issue:

```
CREATE DATABASE test;

CREATE TABLE purchase
(
  id             int          auto_increment primary key,
  provider_id    int          not null,
  create_date    timestamp    null,
  create_user    int          null,
  change_date    timestamp    null,
  change_user    int          null,
  group_id       int          null,
  reference      varchar(45)  null
);

CREATE INDEX purchase_reference_index ON purchase (reference);
CREATE INDEX purchase_provider_index ON purchase (provider_id);

CREATE TABLE provider
(
  id           int auto_increment primary key,
  name         varchar(45) null,
  constraint name_uniq unique (name)
);

CREATE TRIGGER test.purchase_ref_insert
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON test.purchase
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.reference := concat(
      (SELECT name FROM provider WHERE id = NEW.provider_id),
      date_format(NEW.create_date, '%Y%m%d'), '/',
      (SELECT LPAD(IFNULL(MAX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(reference, '/', -1)) + 1, 0), 3, '0')
       FROM purchase
       WHERE date_format(NEW.create_date, '%Y%m%d') = date_format(create_date, '%Y%m%d')
         AND NEW.provider_id = provider_id
      )
  );
END
;

INSERT INTO provider (name) VALUE ('test');


SET time_zone = '+00:00';
INSERT INTO purchase (provider_id, create_date, create_user, group_id)
VALUE (1, '2019-01-30 02:36:58', 1, 3);


SET time_zone = '+05:00';
INSERT INTO purchase (provider_id, create_date, create_user, group_id)
VALUE (1, '2019-01-30 02:36:58', 1, 3);

SET time_zone = '-05:00';
INSERT INTO purchase (provider_id, create_date, create_user, group_id)
VALUE (1, '2019-01-30 02:36:58', 1, 3);


SET time_zone = '+00:00';
SELECT create_date, reference FROM purchase;
```

And here what I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Table structures and data would help here

Comment: Consider using `TIMESTAMP` instead of `DATETIME`.  And be sure each computer has the appropriate timezone set.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I updated the question, please have another look

Comment: @RickJames I was using DATATIME and switched to TIMESTAMP (my problems started when customer want to use different timezones)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :D

I just need to set the timezone inside the trigger `SET time_zone = 'SYSTEM';`

> date_format doesn't respect localized time zone

```
CREATE TRIGGER test.purchase_ref_insert
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON test.purchase
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    SET @time_zone_tmp := @@time_zone;
    SET time_zone = 'SYSTEM';
    SET NEW.reference := concat(
        (SELECT name FROM provider WHERE id = NEW.provider_id),
        date_format(NEW.create_date, '%Y%m%d'), '/',
        (SELECT LPAD(IFNULL(MAX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(reference, '/', -1)) + 1, 0), 3, '0')
         FROM purchase
         WHERE date_format(NEW.create_date, '%Y%m%d') = date_format(create_date, '%Y%m%d')
           AND NEW.provider_id = provider_id
        )
    );
    SET time_zone = @time_zone_tmp;
  END
;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@@session.time_zone` in the trigger to CONVERT_TZ the given timestamp into the SYSTEM time_zone, before comparing against the table.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER purchase_ref_insert
  BEFORE INSERT ON purchase
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 SET @ts := CONVERT_TZ(NEW.create_date, @@session.time_zone, 'SYSTEM');
 SET @providerName := (SELECT name FROM provider WHERE id = NEW.provider_id);
 SET @refPostfix := (
         SELECT 
         LPAD(IFNULL(MAX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(reference, '/', -1)) + 1, 0), 3, '0')
         FROM purchase
         WHERE NEW.provider_id = provider_id
           AND CAST(CONVERT_TZ(create_date, @@session.time_zone, 'SYSTEM') AS DATE) = CAST(@ts AS DATE)
     );
 SET NEW.create_date_tz = @@session.time_zone;
 SET NEW.reference := CONCAT(@providerName, DATE_FORMAT(@ts, '%Y%m%d'), '/', @refPostfix);
END;
```

And you could add an extra column to the table.
One that will contain the session's timezone used when the record was inserted.

```
create_date_tz varchar(6)   not null default 'SYSTEM'
```

This way, you can still show that create_date back in the timezone of the customer.

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=41896763eaa7b45338ab0edfe058d649)*

**For the example:**

```
 SELECT 
  id, create_date, reference, create_date_tz,
  CONVERT_TZ(create_date, 'SYSTEM', create_date_tz) as ts_at_TZ
 FROM purchase;
```

**Returns :**

```
id | create_date         | reference        | create_date_tz | ts_at_TZ           
 1 | 2019-01-30 07:30:01 | test20190130/000 | -05:00         | 2019-01-30 02:30:01
 2 | 2019-01-30 02:30:02 | test20190130/001 | +00:00         | 2019-01-30 02:30:02
 3 | 2019-01-29 21:30:03 | test20190129/000 | +05:00         | 2019-01-30 02:30:03
```

Comment: Using `CONVERT_TZ` seem a clean method, also you moved the `provider_id` condition up for better usage of `primary key` :)
Just to let you know, we need to convert `create_date` in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=04d71e55118f53642fac50e4e2818444) too to avoid duplicate entries.

Comment: We do not realy need `create_date_tz `, MySQL convert all timezone date to UTC, and when a client ask for it, he use the session timezone to convert it back

Comment: Well, the create_date_tz is more a suggestion. It's not really needed, but it could help on your side when you want to query based on the local time of the customer.  But I don't get what you mean by "we need to convert create_date", because the `@ts` variable is the NEW.create_date, just in server's timezone.

Comment: I attached the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=04d71e55118f53642fac50e4e2818444) test, have a look, when addiding another +05:00 +10:00 test we got duplicate ref /000

Comment: To prevent that from happining, I used `CAST(CONVERT_TZ(create_date, @@session.time_zone, 'SYSTEM') AS DATE) = CAST(@ts AS DATE)`

Comment: I will keep, `SET time_zone = 'SYSTEM';` when saving `timestamps`, it will always be converted, so I do not think it will have a side effect ? but for sure I will update the order of the condition

Comment: Thanks. And if that works for you, sure.  Working with timezone's can be odd sometimes.  I tried if `AND CAST(create_date AS DATE) = CAST(NEW.create_date AS DATE)` would work in the trigger. But that didn't work out as expected.